# onclicked on Flexible Fragment Buttons doesn't worked

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to android and I have this problem using Flexible Fragment.
I have a activity called mainActivity and Fragment called RegisteractivityFragment.

I load Fragment in Main Activity but when I click on the Fragments Buttons the App closes.
This is some parts of my registerActivityFragment.java

```
    public class RegisterActivityFragment extends Fragment {


public interface OnButtonsClicked {

    public void onRegisterClicked();
    public void onNextTimeclicked();
}
 OnButtonsClicked buttonClickListener ;

    //some codes

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
        try {
            buttonClickListener = (OnButtonsClicked) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnButtonsClicked Functions");
        }
    }


public void clickRegister(View view)
 {


    buttonClickListener.onRegisterClicked();
 }  
public void clickNextTime(View view)
{

buttonClickListener.onNextTimeclicked();
}



}
```

and this is my MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements    RegisterActivityFragment.OnButtonsClicked {

RegisterActivityFragment registerFragment= new RegisterActivityFragment();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    //adding Fragment to activity



}

    //implementing the interface
@Override
public void onRegisterClicked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"asd",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
    toast.show();
}

@Override
public void onNextTimeclicked() {

    Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"asd",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
    toast.show();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to override onCreateView method in RegisterActivityFragment class to set onClickListner like this

```
private Button foo; // as globle var


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rssitem_detail,
    container, false);
foo = view.findViewByid(R.id.foo); // button id
foo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
      OnButtonsClicked.onRegisterClicked();
   } 
});
return view;
}
```

your problem is in xml file you set attributes OnClick="clickRegister" and defining method in fragment 
Actually you have to defining it in MainActivity not it Fragment

so second way to fix the problem is to move the 2 method to MainActivity those :

```
public void clickRegister(View view)
{


    buttonClickListener.onRegisterClicked();
}  
public void clickNextTime(View view)
{

buttonClickListener.onNextTimeclicked();
}



}
```

Comment: Actually second way fix the problem but do not Applied encapsulation object oriented properties

Comment: mm... but first way is better